# JavaScript _doPostBack error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an html table in my asp.net application. When a td element is clicked, I store td element id in a hidden field using JavaScript. After that, I am forcing _dopostback from JavaScript to use the hidden field value in code behind.

```
<td id="m1" onclick="">Jan</td>
<td id="m2" onclick="">Feb</td>

$('.window td').on('click', function () {
            var idName = this.id;
            var selectedid = idName.substring(1);
            console.log(selectedid);
            $('#hidden').val(selectedid);
            _doPostBack('m1', '');
    });
```

But when I click on td, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: _doPostBack is not defined" error.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__doPostBack` has two underscores in front, not one.

Comment: when you add runat="server" you can get values at serverside i.e in codebehind.